# Custom CSS for Hiding Section on Add Media Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using these CSS for hiding these two whole section.

```
.attachment-details {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;
}

.media-frame-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 150;
    display: none;
}
```

1. Attachment section (Right side).
2. Action section (Left side).. but after using these CSS fields is hide but there are still tabs are showing with action and expand detail titles as you see in image below.

[Please Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htym3.png)

Can anyone please customize this CSS to hide these two whole tab with title also only upload files and media library tab are visible and all other tab will be hide for authors.

Comment: Can you please give us the HTML for this? Thank You

Comment: Sorry, i have only CSS for this work

Comment: Do you Also want to hide this Section

Comment: Can You please share HTML markup so we can give you a better solution.

Comment: @asifshaikhtsn Basically, CSS alone can't give you an appearance of a website since it needs HTML. So, can you please show your HTML in your question? Or is that confidential or you can't share that HTML?